# How to Trigger an ItemInserting event of listview on Enter Key Press

Tags: c#, asp.net

how i can trigger iteminserting event of asp.net Listview control of a row on pressing enter key after entering some values in the textbox in the same row.

Comment: Any effort so far? [FAQ] - [ask]

Comment: yes i used panel inside listview but it didn't work for me.and i used to register enter press key event of textbox in a row but i failed to register .so i can call it from javascript

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may be complicated.  Any control that posts back sets the __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT params to determine what the control event was.  You don't have to set those explicitly; you can use __doPostBack, which sets them.  You have to use the UniqueID of the ListView for the target and whatever the listview expects for the argument (which can be a long concatenated string for some control types), something like:

```
__doPostBack("<%= list.UniqueID %>", "args");
```

The problem is what to supply to the args, and you would have to use RedGate Reflector or Telerik JustDecompile to do that.